# Custom trajectory (non linear)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm working on a little web animation project (moving div in a web page), and I want to use custom trajectory with jQuery or Javascript or any library.

I don't want to use Canvas (which may be more appropriated)

My purpose is maybe difficult : Use the mouse to draw a line and catch all positions and save to animate a div.

I know that jQuery allow to do some stuff but it is linear animation.

I can use the animate function to do this :

```
$(this).animate({left:+500}, 1500, function(){ //first move left
  $(this).animate({right:500}, 1500); // then move right
  //etc... but too many points, sorry for syntax errors
 });
```

It is clearly too long to describe custom moves.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values of the mouse movement in an array and use CSS animation or chain either jQuery `.animate()` or `Element.animate()` calls for each element of the array to achieve expected effect.

Comment: I understand for the animation part. But it's a bit complex to draw a "curved/custom" line in CSS with the mouse in a specific div, without Canvas. Once i have the array of positions, i think i will be able to do the animations through a loop.